# Why is my padding not being applied to my <li>

Tags: html

I'm trying to place a padding around my 3rd li element called "widget-3" however it is not applying the padding. Can anyone help me figure out why this may be happening?

CSS

```
 .footer-widgets {
    width: 93.75%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.footer-widgets li { 
    width:24%; 
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
}

.footer-widgets li p{ 
    width:92%;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 16px;  
}

.footer-widgets li a{ 
    color: #17c3f5;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.footer-widgets li:nth-child(3) { width: 48% }
.widget-3 {background-color: #4f4c4a; border: 1px solid #666462; padding: 10px;}

.widget-3 p { width: 100% }
```

HTML

```
<footer class="clearfix">
<ul class="footer-widgets">

<li class="widget-1">
<h4>About Us</h4>
<p>Once you are on the web, it is even more important to have a unique voice in this competitive cyber market. Additional to web design, I also offer affordable services in logo design, business cards and brochures. Please don't hesitate to contact me and I will be happy to give you a free custom quote within 24 hours. I also offer affordable services in logo design.</p>
<strong>Learn more</strong>
</li>

<li class="widget-2">
<h4>Twitter</h4>
<p><a href="#">@ambergoodwin</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vulputate egestas volutpat. Morbi dignissim sapien sit amet ipsum vestibulum vel vehicula elit convallis. 15 hours ago</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 17 hours ago</p>
<p>Morbi dignissim sapien sit amet ipsum vestibulum vel vehicula elit convallis. 11 hours ago</p>
<strong>Follow us on Twitter</strong>
</li>

<li class="widget-3">
<h4>Services</h4>
<p>Once you are on the web, it is even more important to have a unique voice in this competitive cyber market. Additional to web design, I also offer affordable services in logo design, business cards and brochures. Please don't hesitate to contact me and I will be happy to give you a free custom quote within 24 hours. I also offer affordable services in logo design.</p>
<strong>Learn more</strong>
</li>
</ul>


</footer>
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong for the padding not to work?

Also, can anyone help me see why .widget-3 p {width: 100%} doesn't work?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a link to your page?

Comment: .footer-widgets li is overriding your .widget-3 rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The padding is being set to 0 by `.footer-widgets li` which has more [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) than `.widget-3`.

The width is being set to 92% by `.footer-widgets li p` which has more specificity than `.widget-3 p`.

Just add two new declarations at the end of your css:

```
li.widget-3 {padding: 10px;}
li.widget-3 p { width: 100% }
```

That should fix it.

Comment: It did, thank you. Another question if you don't mind. I see that in IE my `.footer-widgets li:nth-child(3) { width: 46% }` is being ignored. Do you know what I can do to have IE work the same? It's my first time using this method so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Unfortunately, IE has no love for the nth-child selector. See http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/. Fortunately, adding `width: 46%' to 'li.widget-3 {padding: 10px;}' should fix it.

Comment: Thanks. The more I can learn about why classes and elements work and dont work the better.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared the same rule above, but with a different priority.

See the rules for CSS specificity: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html

> Also, can anyone help me see why .widget-3 p {width: 100%} doesn't work?

You're not defining a parent container width.  Your browser is saying "100% of what?"  See your rule for .widget-3.

Comment: I looked it over quickly and I found that placing !important beside both worked. Is that a way to do it?

Comment: Hi Amber.  Check out the link to the specification that I included in my answer - it will give you the tools you need to troubleshoot these common CSS issues.  While you are able to change the priority by adding the !important designator, it can make your CSS unwieldy.  I glanced over some pages and found what appears to be a slightly more "friendly" introduction to how rules are applied: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/.  Let me know if you have any questions and I'll do what I can to help.